# Locale Currency Symbol

Tags: java, android, localization, internationalization, currency

I having some problems getting the default currency symbol of the system.
I am getting the currency symbol this way:

```
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
Log.v("TAG",currency.getSymbol());
```

When the system language is in `English (United States)` the right symbol shows up (`$`).
But when i choose the language `Portuguese (Portugal)` it returns this symbol `¤`.

What can be causing this?

Comment: Maybe you are using UTF-8 instead of UTF-16? I don't see how that could happen, but it is a thought.

Comment: i think this will be a good solution to your answer
Currency.getInstance(new Locale("YOUR LANGUAGE", countryCode)).getSymbol();

Comment: You might get answer to your question from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832655/getting-currency-code-if-we-have-only-country-code-in-database/16833419#16833419)

Answer (score 15):

This seems to be a known issue (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38622.
I came to a possible solution this way:

Since the problem is in the Symbol and not the Currency code, i solved this problem creating a static`Map` where the key is the *CurrencyCode* and the value is the *Symbol*.

```
public static final Map<String, String> MYCURRENCIES = new HashMap<String, String>(){
        {
            put("EUR","€");
            put("USD","$");
            (..)
        }
};
```

In order to get all (or almost) the currencies codes available in the locales information you can do something like this:

```
for (Locale ll: Locale.getAvailableLocales()){
    try {
       Currency a = Currency.getInstance(ll);
       Log.v("MyCurrency",a.getCurrencyCode()+"#"+a.getSymbol());
    }catch (Exception e){
       // when the locale is not supported
  }
}
```

After you created you Map with the *CurrencyCode* and *Symbol* you just have to something like this:

```
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
String curSymbol = MYCURRENCIES.get(currency.getCurrencyCode());
```

Comment: this is pretty cool, thank you. 
ps: for everybody else: instead of Log.v simply 
MYCURRENCIES.put(a.getCurrencyCode(), a.getSymbol());

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts;

1. Could it be that you're getting the right symbol for (Euro) but your font/log doesn't have it and it only looks like that symbol?
2. Locale is a pretty frisky class, it's constructors have no error checking. You can easily see locales that aren't supported or don't really exist in the standards (such as "de_US" for "German as spoken in the US").
3. Note that locale data is not necessarily available for any of the locales pre-defined as constants in this class except for en_US, which is the only locale Java guarantees is always available, and it differs in different Android releases, and also can be limited by the operator or custom builds. [pt_PT was added in 2.3](http://colincooper.net/blog/2011/02/17/android-supported-language-and-locales/).
4. Regarding the option you presented, if you check out [Unicode's standards](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads/cldr-1-7) as they have been implemented in API8 and up, Portugal exists only as a territory (and not the combination).
5. It may be better if you therefore create a partial locale instance from the country code alone, and then get the currency symbol for Portugal for instance. You will not be able to comply with the predefined [statics of Locale's class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) as it pretty narrowly supports different locales (It's a short list), but it should work as this locale has the data you are looking for in the system.
6. I would also try and see if currency.toString() returns the EUR (the ISO 4217 code of the currency, usually a three letter acronym).

Answer (score 1):

```
NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    String cur = currencyFormatter.format(yourValue);
```

This Formats your int/double to a currency based on the Device Language

```
    String currency = cur.replaceAll("[0-9.,]","");
```

And this is how to get just the currency Symbol, by replacing all numbers, dots and commas