# getting currency code if we have only country code in database

Tags: java, android, currency

i have problem getting the country currency, i am having the country code in database through these code i have to get the country code in java how do i make the code for this please suggest me.
i m trying with this example but its not working.

```
    class Utils {
    public static SortedMap<Currency, Locale> currencyLocaleMap;
    static {
        currencyLocaleMap = new TreeMap<Currency, Locale>(
                new Comparator<Currency>() {
                    public int compare(Currency c1, Currency c2) {
                        return c1.getCurrencyCode().compareTo(
                                c2.getCurrencyCode());
                    }
                });
        for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
            try {
                Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
                currencyLocaleMap.put(currency, locale);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static String getCurrencySymbol(String currencyCode) {
        Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode);
        System.out.println(currencyCode + ":-"
                + currency.getSymbol(currencyLocaleMap.get(currency)));
        return currency.getSymbol(currencyLocaleMap.get(currency));
    }
}

  public class GetCurrency {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Utils.getCurrencySymbol(Currency.getInstance("INR").getCurrencyCode());
        Utils.getCurrencySymbol(Currency.getInstance(Locale.JAPAN)
                .getCurrencyCode());
        Utils.getCurrencySymbol(Currency.getInstance(Locale.UK)
                .getCurrencyCode());

        Utils.getCurrencySymbol("INR");
    }
}
```

Comment: "it's not working" - can you explain further? Which parts don't work, what problems are you seeing?

Comment: @Rup if i changed the "INR" to another like "BMD" whose symbol is $ then its throwing null pointer excetpion

Comment: Have you debugged it? What is null? If you have a specific question then update your question. Otherwise it will get closed.

Comment: @Jamie yeah i have debugged it those currency code are already present in locale are properly showing their symbol but those are not present in locale  throwing null pointer exception i have download some currency code from google some of them like USD,AUD are working but for BMD,BZD are not working how to make these working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the solution for my problem this is the code i have done.

```
        public static Map<Currency, Locale> getCurrencyLocaleMap() {
        Map<Currency, Locale> currencyLocaleMap = new HashMap<Currency, Locale>();
        for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
            try {
                Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
                currencyLocaleMap.put(currency, locale);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return currencyLocaleMap;
    }

    public static String getCurrencySymbol(String currencyCode) {
        String currencySymbol = null;
        if (currencyCode == null || currencyCode.isEmpty()) {
            currencySymbol = currencyCode;
        } else {
            Locale currencyLocale = null;
            Map<Currency, Locale> currencyLocaleMap = null;
            Currency currency = null;
            try {
                currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode);
                currencyLocaleMap = getCurrencyLocaleMap();
                currencyLocale = currencyLocaleMap.get(currency);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("No symbol is there for currencyCode="
                        + currencyCode);
            }
            if (currency != null && currencyLocale != null) {
                currencySymbol = currency.getSymbol(currencyLocaleMap
                        .get(currency));
            } else {
                currencySymbol = currencyCode;
            }
        }
        return currencySymbol;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Try:

```
//to retrieve currency code
public static String getCurrencyCode(String countryCode) {
    return Currency.getInstance(new Locale("", countryCode)).getCurrencyCode(); 
}

//to retrieve currency symbol 
public static String getCurrencySymbol(String countryCode) {
    return Currency.getInstance(new Locale("", countryCode)).getSymbol(); 
}
```

Comment: new Locale(null, countryCode) will throw Exception, null cannot be passed as param

Comment: and empty string?

Comment: @Puce This code gives NPE as the locale returned when we pass an empty string in the language is "_IND" which it says not supported by Currency class.

Answer (score 2):

Debug to determine which currencies are available.

```
    Set<Currency> avail = Currency.getAvailableCurrencies();
    for (Currency next : avail) {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("displayName="+next.getDisplayName());
        System.out.println("currencyCode="+next.getCurrencyCode());
        System.out.println("numericCode="+next.getNumericCode());
        System.out.println("symbol="+next.getSymbol());
        System.out.println("toString="+next.toString());
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    }
```

If any needed currencies are missing/wrong, follow the instructions from the javadoc:

> Users can supersede the Java runtime currency data by creating a properties file named `<JAVA_HOME>/lib/currency.properties`. The contents of the properties file are key/value pairs of the ISO 3166 country codes and the ISO 4217 currency data respectively. The value part consists of three ISO 4217 values of a currency, i.e., an alphabetic code, a numeric code, and a minor unit. Those three ISO 4217 values are separated by commas. The lines which start with '#'s are considered comment lines. For example,

```
#Sample currency properties
JP=JPZ,999,0
```

> will supersede the currency data for Japan.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.commons.lang.LocaleUtils;

public class Test {


    public static String getCurrenyCodeByCountryCode(String countryCode) {

        String currencyCode="USD";

        try {
            List<Locale> locales=LocaleUtils.languagesByCountry(countryCode);

            Currency currency=Currency.getInstance(locales.get(0));

            currencyCode=currency.getCurrencyCode();


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return currencyCode;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        System.out.println(getCurrenyCodeByCountryCode("IN"));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple option that fulfills this requirement:

```
public static String getCurrencySymbol(String countryCode) {
    String currencySymbol = "";
    Locale locale = null;
    Currency currency = null;
    try {
        locale = new Locale("", countryCode);
        currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (currency != null) {
        currencySymbol = currency.getCurrencyCode();
    }

    return currencySymbol;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String getSymbol(String countryCode) {
    Locale[] availableLocales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    for (int i = 0; i < availableLocales.length; i++) {
        if (availableLocales[i].getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase(countryCode))
            return Currency.getInstance(availableLocales[i]).getCurrencyCode();
    }
    return "";
}
```