# Android: convert currency symbol into currency code

Tags: android, google-analytics, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, currency

I am using in-app billing and I would like to log the purchases into Google Analytics e-commerce:

- the in-app billing provides the price in the "number symbol" format (e.g. "1.99 €"), from where I can get the currency symbol (e.g. "€", "£")
- Google Analytics e-commerce needs the currency code (e.g. "EUR", "GBP")

how can I convert the currency symbol into the currency code?

Comment: this post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694192/locale-currency-symbol

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you explored Currency in util. If not, please try http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Currency.html

Comment: yes, I did, but I still can't find a way to convert the currency symbol into the currency code