# What is the correct way to get Currency Symbol in Android?

Tags: java, android

This code is working fine but if I change my device langauge this is also show Rs so what the correct way to get currency symbol ?

```
public void displayTotlaPrice() {
    TextView totalPriceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_Price);
    totalPriceTextView.setText("Rs" + displayCalculatePrice());
}
```

Comment: perhaps this answer might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36258674/1388715

Comment: also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14685495/3496570

Answer (score 5):

```
    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
    String symbol = currency.getSymbol().replaceAll("\\w", "");
```

Answer (score 4):

try this, Hope it works.

```
yourString= NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(yourNumber);
```

or

```
NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
String cur = currencyFormatter.format(yourValue);
```

for specific

```
yourString= NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "AU")).format(yourNumber);
```

number will format based on device language.

Detail:

[How to get currency symbol by currency name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258511/how-to-get-currency-symbol-by-currency-name)

[Currency](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Currency.html)

Answer (score 0):

Store below variable in `string.xml`

```
<string name="Rs">\u20B9</string>
```

Now call it as below wherever you want to display `Rs` symbol,

```
textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Rs) + "500");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use,

```
    Locale swedishLocale = new Locale("sv", "SE");
    Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(swedishLocale);
    System.out.println("Symbol: " + currency.getSymbol());
```

for more details, visit [display the currency for a locale](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-display-the-currency-for-a-locale.html)